# Бивак или бивуак?

Tags: грамотная-речь, орфография

Встречаю в тексте разное написание этого слова. То пишут "бивуак", то - "бивак". В смысле, привал, как правило на пути военного марша.
Как я понимаю, слово это французское, да? Тогда подскажите, пожалуйста, как все-таки правильно его писать: бивак или бивуак?
Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Словари дают варианты как более или менее равноправные.
При этом можно заключить, что форма "бивуак" пришла напрямую из французского, а "бивак" - посредством немецкого или же в результате адаптации к русскому языку.

http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E1%E8%E2*%E0%EA&all=x

Я думаю, что правильным будет считать, что современная фактически сложившаяся норма - **бивак**.

Историческое заимствование **бивуак**, более близкое к французскому источнику подверглось упрощению в соответствии с фонетическими тенденциями русского языка (избегать зияния гласных). Но оно вполне может быть использовано, например, для стилизации текста.

Comment: а вообще-то бувак, место для перемотки портянок. От переобуться.
Слишком много фамилий и слов осталось--бувак, бувач, бывалый, обувь, обутки.

Обувь

обувь о́бувь ж., укр. обу́в᾽я, русск.-цслав. обувь ж. ὑπόδημα, чеш., слвц. obuv, польск. obuw ж., obuwie. От обу́ть (см.). Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс М. Р. Фасмер 1964—1973